# Form Groups with a Modal in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following modal. I am trying to use form groups to put 2 or 4 form groups on the same line, but it is not working. It looks pretty ugly having so much space for form input. Any idea if I can use form groups inside a modal? Here is the code:

```
<Modal size={size} open={open} onClose={closeModal}>
    <Modal.Header>
        Generated Channel Information
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Content style={styles.modalContent}>
            <Form.Input fluid label='LID' name='lid' value={lid} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input fluid label='Channel Number' name='hfivePrimaryPortValue' value={channelNum}  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input fluid label='Origin Group' name='hfivePrimaryPortValue' value={originGroup}  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input fluid label='Directory' name='hfivePrimaryPortValue' value={directory}  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                <Form.Select fluid search label='H5 Encoder' name='packagers' value={packagers} options={languages} placeholder='Choose Audio Channels' onChange={this.handleAudioInputChange} multiple = "true" />
                <Form.Select fluid search label='H5 Pair Encoder' name='packagers' value={packagers} options={languages} placeholder='Choose Audio Channels' onChange={this.handleAudioInputChange} multiple = "true" />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                <Form.Select fluid search label='Titan Encoder' name='packagers' value={packagers} options={languages} placeholder='Choose Audio Channels' onChange={this.handleAudioInputChange} multiple = "true" />
                <Form.Select fluid search label='Titan Pair Encoder' name='packagers' value={packagers} options={languages} placeholder='Choose Audio Channels' onChange={this.handleAudioInputChange} multiple = "true" />
                <Form.Select fluid search label='Titan Packager' name='packagers' value={packagers} options={languages} placeholder='Choose Audio Channels' onChange={this.handleAudioInputChange} multiple = "true" />
                <Form.Select fluid search label='H5 Packager' name='packagers' value={packagers} options={languages} placeholder='Choose Audio Channels' onChange={this.handleAudioInputChange} multiple = "true" />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Input fluid label='Destination IP' name='hfivePrimaryPortValue' value={destinationIP}  onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
    </Modal.Content>
    <Modal.Actions style={{padding: '0.7em'}}>
    <Button content='Close and Continue Editing' floated='left'
        style={{margin: 0}} onClick={this.closeModal} />

    <Button negative content='Submit'
    style={{margin: 0}} onClick={this.submitModal} />
    </Modal.Actions>
</Modal>]
```

[image]

Comment: refer this https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/